# Session logs out automatically in Ubuntu 22.04 while using chrome

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, session, logout

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 from last some months.
And I'm constantly facing this issue.

Issue :- While working on Chrome Browser for sometimes my browser automatically closes and sometime my current session logs out automatically and then I have to login again in order to use my laptop.

Device Specs:-
RAM - 4GB
Model - Dell Inspiron 3542

Can anyone help me to get rid of this.

Comment: Very strange.  When you log in, can you run `dmesg` in a terminal and see if it says anything about logout or hibernation/suspend or anything, and post it in your question if it does?  Not sure what might cause this without more hints.

Comment: When I encounter it next, do the same as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure yours in this case or not.

If you toggle "Download and install automatically"
in the Software update settings "When there are security updates"

The system automatically reboot when the update requires reboot and the computer becomes idle. So when you or me leave the Google-Chrome for coffee break, it reboots silently.

To prevent this, open the following file

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

```
// Automatically reboot *WITHOUT CONFIRMATION* if
//  the file /var/run/reboot-required is found after the upgrade
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";
```

Uncomment the "Unattended-Upgrade..." not to reboot automatically.

Comment: bash: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades: Permission denied  After running the above line I'm getting this error.

Comment: Use your favorite text-editor `sudo vi !!`

Comment: did the same as you said, Thanks for this.